# Include nested map array values in search results

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an arbitrary number of objects in an array, and each of those objects has a nested array of subValues. I am working on being able to filter components using search. I am able to successfully search the parent level objects, but I'm stuck at wanting to be able to also filter based on each top levels nested array of values.

In my case, I can search the `value`, which is a string, but I don't know how to search the `subValues`, which is an array containing an arbitrary number of strings.

In my snippet below, you can see that searching, 'one', 'two', etc, will return the parent level `value`, but if you try to search 'sub', nothing will return from the array `subValues`.

[jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/schrdr/bxkh1g4a/). snippet below.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            currentValue: null,
            search: '',
        }
    }

    updateSearch = (event) => {
        this.setState({
            search: event.target.value,
        })
    }

    render() {
        const Values = {
            valuesList: [{
                value: 'value one',
                subValues: [
                    'sub value one',
                    'sub value two',
                ]
            }, {
                value: 'value two',
                subValues: [
                    'sub value three',
                    'sub value four',
                ]
            }, {
                value: 'value three',
                subValues: [
                    'sub value five',
                    'sub value six',
                ]
            }
            ]
        };

        let filteredValues = Values.valuesList.filter(
            (values) => {
                return (
                    values.value.toLocaleLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.search.toLocaleLowerCase()) !== -1
                );
            }
        );

        var renderValues = filteredValues.map((valueItem, i) => {
            var renderSubValues = valueItem.subValues.map((subValues, j) => {
                return (
                    <p key={j}>{subValues}</p>
                )
            });
            return (
                <div
                    onClick={() => this.getValue(valueItem.value)}
                    key={i}
                >
                    <p>{valueItem.value}</p>
                    <p>{renderSubValues}</p>
                </div>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                    placeholder="search"
                    type="text"
                    value={this.state.search}
                    onChange={this.updateSearch.bind(this)}
                />
                {renderValues}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

div {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your filter method can be modified to also check `subValues`.

We can use JavaScript's [some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method along with [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to do that.

```
 let filteredValues = Values.valuesList.filter(
   (values) => {
     return (
       values.value.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||
       values.subValues.some(item => item.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
     );
   }
 );
```

**Demo:**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentValue: null,
      search: '',
    }
  }

  updateSearch = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      search: event.target.value,
    })
  }

  render() {
    const Values = {
      valuesList: [{
        value: 'value one',
        subValues: [
          'sub value one',
          'sub value two',
        ]
      }, {
        value: 'value two',
        subValues: [
          'sub value three',
          'sub value four',
        ]
      }, {
        value: 'value three',
        subValues: [
          'sub value five',
          'sub value six',
        ]
      }]
    };

    let filteredValues = Values.valuesList.filter(
            (values) => {
                return (
                    values.value.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLocaleLowerCase()) ||  values.subValues.some(item => item.toLocaleLowerCase().includes(this.state.search.toLocaleLowerCase()))
                );
            }
        );

    var renderValues = filteredValues.map((valueItem, i) => {
      var renderSubValues = valueItem.subValues.map((subValues, j) => {
        return ( <
          p key = {
            j
          } > {
            subValues
          } < /p>
        )
      });
      return ( <
        div onClick = {
          () => this.getValue(valueItem.value)
        }
        key = {
          i
        } >
        <
        p > {
          valueItem.value
        } < /p> <
        p > {
          renderSubValues
        } < /p> < /
        div >
      )
    })
    return ( <
        div >
        <
        input placeholder = "search"
        type = "text"
        value = {
          this.state.search
        }
        onChange = {
          this.updateSearch.bind(this)
        }
        /> {
        renderValues
      } <
      /div>
  )
}
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.querySelector("#app"))
```

```css
body {
  background: #20262E;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}

#app {
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
}

div {
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```